# Create columns based on date filter within group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

**I have the following data:**

```
> dput(my_data)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), begin = c("2017-01-01", 
"2017-08-01", "2022-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-01-01", 
"2017-09-01"), end = c("2017-07-01", "2022-04-01", "2023-06-01", 
"2017-08-01", "2023-06-01", "2017-08-01", "2023-06-01"), position = c("position_1", 
"position_2", "position_3", "position_1", "position_2", "position_1", 
"position_1")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")


 id      begin        end   position
1  1 2017-01-01 2017-07-01 position_1
2  1 2017-08-01 2022-04-01 position_2
3  1 2022-05-01 2023-06-01 position_3
4  2 2017-01-01 2017-08-01 position_1
5  2 2017-09-01 2023-06-01 position_2
6  3 2017-01-01 2017-08-01 position_1
7  3 2017-09-01 2023-06-01 position_1
```

**What I want:**
I am trying to create a new column (e.g. `first_position_in_2023`) that contains the **first** position for each `id` that was present in 2023-01-01. (The first position with a timestamp begin-end that includes 2023-01-01.

So for my Data:

- id == 1: position_3
- id == 2: position_2
- id == 2: position_1

Ideally I would want to be able to create multiple columns like:

- first_position_in_2017
- first_position_in_2018
- first_position_in_2019
  ...

**What I tried:**

```
my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(first_position_in_2023 = position[begin <= (as.Date("2023-01-01"))])


# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id first_position_in_2023
  <dbl> <chr>                 
1     1 position_1            
2     1 position_2            
3     1 position_3            
4     2 position_1            
5     2 position_2            
6     3 position_1            
7     3 position_1
```

This seems to give me just the result per Row and not the **first** result for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you include all the tags, you could try this `dplyr`/`tidyr`/`lubridate` approach for the broader goal of doing it for each year:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(end)) %>% select(-c(begin, end)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = position, 
              names_glue = "first_position_in_{year}")
```

Output:

```
    id first_position_in_2017 first_position_in_2022 first_position_in_2023
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                 
1     1 position_1             position_2             position_3            
2     2 position_1             NA                     position_2            
3     3 position_1             NA                     position_1
```

---

Per your comment, if you wanted to create columns for years that are not in the data (ie, 2019, 2020, etc), you could use `complete` just before `pivot_wider`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(end)) %>% select(-c(begin, end)) %>%
  complete(year = min(year):max(year)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = position, 
              names_glue = "first_position_in_{year}") %>% filter(!is.na(id))
```

Output

```
     id first_position_in_2017 first_position_in_2018 first_position_in_2019 first_position_in_2020 first_position_in_2021 first_position_in_2022 first_position_in_2023
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                 
1     1 position_1             NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                     position_2             position_3            
2     2 position_1             NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                     position_2            
3     3 position_1             NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA                     position_1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I corrected the typo. As for your answer: It does work for the years that are given in the dataset. However, how would I calculate `first_position_in_2019` for example? With `pivot_wider` I would need to have all years within my original dataset, which i dont. And for `first_position_in_2022` in id 1 and 2 the result should still be position_1, as it is the first "valid" position that is present in "2022-01-01".

Comment: @fschier Gotcha - Just to make sure I understand - in the full dataset you dont have anyone in year 2019, but still want a column `first_position_in_2019`?

Comment: correct, thanks for your addition - using the `complete` does solve the Problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to accomplish the same:

```
fn <- function(year, begin, end, pos){
  yr <- as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01'))
  res <- pos[begin < yr & yr < end]
  if(length(res)) res else NA
}

yrs <- 2017:2023
names(yrs) <- paste0('first_pos_in_', yrs)

my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(yrs, fn, begin, end, position))



    id begin  end   position first_pos_in_2017 first_pos_in_2018 first_pos_in_2019
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <lgl>             <chr>             <chr>            
1     1 2017-… 2017… positio… NA                position_2        position_2       
2     1 2017-… 2022… positio… NA                position_2        position_2       
3     1 2022-… 2023… positio… NA                position_2        position_2       
4     2 2017-… 2017… positio… NA                position_2        position_2       
5     2 2017-… 2023… positio… NA                position_2        position_2       
6     3 2017-… 2017… positio… NA                position_1        position_1       
7     3 2017-… 2023… positio… NA                position_1        position_1       
# ℹ 4 more variables: first_pos_in_2020 <chr>, first_pos_in_2021 <chr>,
#   first_pos_in_2022 <chr>, first_pos_in_2023 <chr>
```